# How to increase 400 V to 1600 V? Or oscillate the 400 V for a voltage multiplier?

Tags: voltage, switching

I am using a flyback transformer to obtain 400 V DC from 120 V AC mains. I cannot find a transformer and switching controller available which give a higher output voltage, and do not want to deal with higher output voltages from this transformer either as it would require filter caps with larger voltage tolerances.

Therefore, I plan on using a voltage multiplier to quadruple this 400 V output. In order to do that, I need to oscillate this new input voltage to the voltage multiplier circuit (400 V) between 0 V and 400 V.

How can I go about making this oscillation circuit?

Frequency is not too important, 10 Hz to 100 kHz is in the range. Also, this 1.6 kV ouput will experience zero load under normal conditions, therefore a feedback control to stop the oscillation once the output is charged would be beneficial (as no switching power will be wasted).

I considered using a voltage divider, with an N MOSFET replacing the low side resistor, and driving the FET to oscillate the voltage, and it worked for lower voltages (12 V) but experienced some trouble when I tried the circuit with 400 V input.

I am considering a digital inverter type circuit driven by a 555 timer. Is this a good approach to follow? I have worked plenty with N FETs but am hesitant on how to drive the high side P FET given such a high voltage. I appreciate your suggestions.

This question should not be marked as a duplicate. The other question asks for different circuits to generate a high voltage. This question specifically focuses on how to create an AC voltage from a high DC voltage, sine, square, or otherwise.

Comment: Wind your own flyback transformer. You already have a working primary side so use that.

Comment: Your "flyback transformer" is obviously more than a transformer.  Sounds like some kind of switch mode powersupply.  But, why not just use the 120VAC to power a voltage multiplier?  You'd only need a couple of stages more to get 1600V than you would need to get there from 400V.

Comment: It's possible to design any power supply to step up the regular mains voltage to whatever you want, but you need also to specify how much current you need. There are simple transformers that you can buy on ebay that transfrom 110V 60hz to maybe 5KV AC at a few milliamps. Do you need a DC output or an AC one, and at what frequency? Are you just trying to create a spark? Or are you powering a device with specific requirements? Your question is very under-constrained.

Comment: @JRE For safety reasons, galvanic isolation is required. Also small size is important, therefore I chose to use a flyback transformer which can be operated in the kHz range instead of the 60 Hz from the wall.

Comment: @Robotbugs The 1.6 kV output is DC, other than charging an output capacitor, no current is needed during regular operation. When current is drawn from the cap, it would be in the 1 mA range. Isolation and small size are a priority, therefore the use of a flyback transformer which I can operate at 100 kHz instead of the 60 Hz mains. The large voltage is used to create an electric field in a ionization chamber, similar to those found in Geiger counters.

Comment: Then a 1:1 isolation transformer gives you the isolation.  Or, use a step up to get up to 400VAC or there about then use a multiplier from there.

Comment: @JRE A 1:1 isolation transformer would be for the mains 60 Hz, flyback transformers are much smaller for the same power (and I need very small package). Yes 400 V AC is what I am trying to obtain, whether sine, square, or anything in between. I need to oscillate the 400 V for the voltage multiplier to work.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a flyback transformer to obtain 400 V DC from 120 V AC
>   mains.

OK, so instead of rectifying this output in the conventional way, attach a cockcroft walton multiplier to the output like in this flyback converter: -

[image]

The above is not an exact drop-in for what you want but is intended to show that a relatively high voltage secondary on a flyback transformer can be boosted by a cockcroft walton type multiplier.

Comment: I am using a flyback transformer to obtain the 400 V DC from mains. I do not want to have more than 500 V across any one component. This is one of the reasons I am using the voltage (Cockcroft Walton) multiplier. I need to oscillate this 400 V DC to get the multiplier to work. That is where I am stuck.

Comment: Read my answer again and tell me where you are misunderstanding it.